# Django pass selected object from form to another form

Tags: python, django, forms, object, send

I got 2 pages. Step 2 and Step 3. What I'm trying to do is pass the selected object from the step 2 form, to the step 3 form so I can filter the objects of the Step 3 forms. You can see the 2 pages/forms in the images below. So when a user selects a university in step 2, then the step 3 must show only the courses of the selected university.

My current code is really simple since I'm deleting and re-writing the code for the past days without results.

views.py

```
def step2(request):
    universities = University.objects.order_by('name').distinct()
    return render_to_response("registration/step2.html", {'universities': universities},  RequestContext(request))

def step3(request):
    courses = Course.objects.order_by('name')
    return render_to_response("registration/step3.html", {'courses': courses},  RequestContext(request))
```

[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Can anyone link a similar example for a CBV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view, you have to retrieve the selection that the user made and use it to filter the choices for the next form. Something like:

```
form = FirstForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    uni = form.cleaned_data['uni']
    courses = Course.objects.filter(university__name=uni).order_by('name')
    return render_to_response("registration/step3.html", {'courses': courses},  RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank for your quick answer! By `cleaned_data['uni']` i'm getting the value `12` of the `<option value="12">Example University</option>`? or the `Example University`? Also not sure what to enter in the forms.py:
`class FirstForm(forms.Form): university = forms.CharField()`
Finally since this is for the **def step2** what should I add to **def step3**? Thanks once again! (**Update**: As now, it goes to step 3 but the select course widget is empty, so I guess there is something wrong in the filtering)

Comment: First, you should use the id of the university for option value or some other identifier. That way, you can use that when doing the filtering, i.e `Course.objects.filter(university__id=uni_id)`. If the course select is empty, test if you send any courses from the back-end.

Comment: Yes you're correct! One last question, using this code, when you submit the form, the URL stays the same **/step/2/** instead of going to **/step/3/**. Everything is working but the number in the URL doesn't change.

Comment: Well, you need to change the URL yourself in your template.

Comment: The thing is that there are 2 forms/pages. So when in step 2, it should be step/2/ and when clicking submit, step/3/.